# Foreign Key mapping to composite keys in entity framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

Trying to setup the following relationship with entity framework code first. The following code does not work I've tried many variations... does anyone have a clue?

```
CONSTRAINT [FK_EVENT_Contact] FOREIGN KEY (Patient_ID,[Contact_ID]) REFERENCES
[PatientContact](Patient_ID,Person_ID)



public class PatientContact
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Person_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Person Person { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int Patient_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }
}

public class Event
{
    [Key]
    public int Event_ID { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int EventType_ID {get;set;}
    public virtual EventType EventType { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("Patient")]
    public int Patient_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual Patient Patient { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PatientContact")]
    public int Contact_ID { get; set; }
    public virtual PatientContact PatientContact { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! What error are you getting? What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 18):

You have 2 options here.

Use attributes as you have eg:

```
[ForeignKey("PatientContact"), Column(Order = 0)]
public int Person_ID{ get; set; }
[ForeignKey("PatientContact"), Column(Order = 1)]
public int Patient_ID{ get; set; }
public virtual PatientContact PatientContact { get; set; }
```

Use the model builder (fluent api)

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Event>()
    .HasRequired(p => p.PatientContact)
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey(p => new {p.Person_ID, p.Patient_ID});
```