# Create a 1 to 1 relation when the Primary Key consist of 2 keys with entity framework

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have an 1 to 1 relation between 3 tables.

The parent table has 2 primary keys (composite keys). Lets name them StudentId1 and StudentId2.

What is with the related table where I would put the

```
  [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
```

I do not only have ONE property!

Should I do it like that? Writing StudentId1StudentId2 as Key property for the related Table doesn`t make sense.

RelatedTable:

```
[Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
public int StudentId1 { get; set; }

[Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
public int StudentId2 { get; set; }
```

traditional sample:

```
public class Student
{
    public Student() { }

    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string StudentName { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }

}



public class StudentAddress 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student")]
    public int StudentId { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whats the point of separating the Student and its address if you don't want to have a one-many relationship? You can place the Address class' properties next to the Students class' properties.

Comment: Whats the point of having a Student and StudentAddress entity? Same question. But still those scenario exist. Separation of logical data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't `Column(Order = X)` work?

```
public class Student
{   
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int StudentId1 { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int StudentId2 { get; set; }

    public virtual StudentAddress StudentAddress { get; set; }
}


public class StudentAddress 
{
    [Key, ForeignKey("Student"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public int StudentId1 { get; set; }

    [Key, ForeignKey("Student"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public int StudentId2 { get; set; }

    public virtual Student Student { get; set; }
}
```

**See**

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591583.aspx
- [Foreign Key mapping to composite keys in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059231/foreign-key-mapping-to-composite-keys-in-entity-framework)

Comment: do I have to use: public virtual Student Student { get; set; } on the StudentAddress ? I never want to load a StudentAddress, just a Student and via virtual studentAddress the related ad.dress

Comment: I think you have to for the data annotation to know which model class the `ForeignKey` is referencing, otherwise you would have to set the key using fluent api.