# Problems with Primary Keys and Foreign Keys

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to create one-to-one relation between 2 classes with a composite key. I've done it before in classes with simple PK and it works but now i need to join a class with composite PK and is not working.

Here is the code, I am trying to join SFI_EstadisticaVentasFcst with SFI_Clientes

```
public class SFI_Clientes
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ID_Empresa { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Fecha_Desde { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]       
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public DateTime Fecha_Hasta { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("NOMBRE")]
    public string nombre { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ID VENDEDOR")]
    public string ID_Vendedor { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ID NAM")]
    public string ID_NAM { get; set; }
    [DisplayName("ID KAM")]
    public string ID_KAM { get; set; }

    public virtual SFI_Vendedor vendedor { get; set; }
    public virtual SFI_Kam kam { get; set; }
    public virtual SFI_Nam nam { get; set; }

}

public class SFI_EstadisticaVentasFcst
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]
    public decimal anio { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:0}")]
    public decimal periodo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("cliente"), Column(Order = 0)]
    public string ID_Empresa { get; set; }
    [Key]        
    [ForeignKey("cliente"), Column(Order = 1)]
    public string ID_Cliente { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 3)]
    public string producto { get; set; }
    public decimal fcst_cajas { get; set; }
    public decimal fcst_niv { get; set; }
    public decimal fcst_gsu { get; set; }
    public decimal venta_cajas { get; set; }
    public decimal venta_niv { get; set; }
    public decimal venta_gsu { get; set; }
    public decimal avance_cajas { get; set; }
    public decimal avance_gsu {get; set; }

    public virtual SFI_Clientes cliente { get; set; }
    public virtual SFI_JerarquiaProductos jerarquiaProductos { get; set; }
```

Here is the problemn:

```
public JsonResult cargarListaEmpresas(string idEmpresa, string cliente, string vendedor, string nam, string kam, string categoriaProductos, DateTime fechaDesde, DateTime fechaHasta )
    {
        var c = db.SFI_EstadisticaVentasFcstDbSet.Where
            (x =>
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(idEmpresa) ? true : x.ID_Empresa== idEmpresa) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cliente) ? true : x.ID_Cliente == cliente) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(vendedor) ? true : x.cliente.ID_Vendedor == vendedor) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(kam) ? true : x.cliente.ID_KAM == kam) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(nam) ? true : x.cliente.ID_NAM == nam) &&
            (string.IsNullOrEmpty(categoriaProductos) ? true : x.jerarquiaProductos.descripcion_1 == categoriaProductos) &&
            (x.cliente.Fecha_Desde == fechaDesde) &&
            (x.cliente.Fecha_Hasta == fechaHasta)
            ).Distinct().OrderBy(s => s.ID_Empresa).Select(x => new SelectListItem
            {
                Text = x.ID_Empresa.ToString(),
                Value = x.ID_Empresa
            }).Distinct().OrderBy(x => x.Text).ToList();

        ViewBag.empresas = c;
        return Json(c, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

The error is:
"One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:
SFI_EstadisticaVentasFcst_cliente_Target_SFI_EstadisticaVentasFcst_cliente_Source: : The number of properties in the Dependent and Principal Roles in a relationship constraint must be identical."

Comment: Well , the PK consists of 4 fields and you are trying to setup a FK by 2 fields. This is not gonna happen. As clearly indicated by the error message.

Comment: but i don't have the other 2 fields in the other class, i don't know what to do

Comment: Then unfortunately nothing can be done. EF supports only FK relationships to PK. You are using EF6, right?

Comment: Yes, EF6. So you are saying I should do it without EF?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Foreign Key mapping to composite keys in entity framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059231/foreign-key-mapping-to-composite-keys-in-entity-framework) The linked question seems to provide a solution for both annotations or FluentAPI.

Comment: I'll ready that. Thank you :D